# Laravel - application showing old views after making changes

Tags: php, laravel, view, upload, xampp

I am working on a Laravel template. I have made changes in the public folder while using xampp.
however, when I upload the project to live hosting, the application is showing the old unchanged view but it loads properly when I load it with xampp

I have tried clearing commands but no luck:

```
php artisan cache:clear

php artisan route:cache

php artisan view:clear

php artisan config:cache
```

Please how can I get past this issue?

Comment: Did you also try to clear your browsers cache?

Comment: Are you using a certain content delivery network, like CloudFlare for example? You may need to clear the cache there too.

Comment: Yes I have cleared the cache and no I'm not using any content delivery network yet

Answer (score 0):

PHP on the server itself can cache scripts (which are what views are). The simplest option, if you have access, is to restart or reload your  webserver process (I usually see this myself with php-fpm). You can also try manually clearing PHP's opcache. If you regularly make site changes and have this problem, you should evaluate the performance trade-off of disabling the opcache.

To clear the opcache: `opcache_reset()`

Dealing with the opcache can be complicated, so I recommend you read the documentation if you want to go that route: https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.opcache.php

Answer (score -1):

In linux:
`rm /my/laravel/folder/storage/framework/views/*.php`